# Docker LAMP Container MySQL Permission Denied

Tags: php, mysql, docker, apache, ubuntu

I have a LAMP server configured in docker for local development. It was an Ubuntu 16, Apache, PHP 7.2, MySQL 5.6 setup, so I can run something like this:

`docker run -d -p 80:80 -v ${PWD}:/app --name website_test lamp-server:latest`

I'm trying to upgrade it to Ubuntu 22, PHP 8, MySQL 8.0. Here is part of the Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:jammy
MAINTAINER Ray Hwang <ray.hwang@originalfunction.com>

# Install packages
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get -y install libaio1 libaio-dev supervisor git apache2 curl mysql-server php libapache2-mod-php8.0 php-mbstring php-mysql php-curl php-gd && \
  echo "ServerName localhost" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

# Add image configuration and scripts
ADD docker/start-apache2.sh /start-apache2.sh
ADD docker/start-mysqld.sh /start-mysqld.sh
ADD docker/mysql-setup.sh /mysql-setup.sh
ADD docker/run.sh /run.sh
RUN chmod 755 /*.sh

ADD docker/my.cnf /etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf
ADD docker/supervisord-apache2.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord-apache2.conf
ADD docker/supervisord-mysqld.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord-mysqld.conf

# Add MySQL utils
RUN usermod -d /var/lib/mysql/ mysql

# config to enable .htaccess
ADD docker/apache_default /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
RUN a2enmod rewrite

# Configure /app folder
RUN mkdir -p /app && rm -fr /var/www/html && ln -s /app /var/www/html

#Environment variables to configure php
ENV PHP_UPLOAD_MAX_FILESIZE 128M
ENV PHP_POST_MAX_SIZE 128M

# Add volumes for MySQL 
VOLUME  ["/etc/mysql", "/var/lib/mysql", "/app" ]

EXPOSE 80 3306
CMD ["/run.sh"]
```

After building the image, everything seems to work fine, except connecting to MySQL through Apache.

Here is what does work:

- Connecting to MySQL via CLI

  ```
  $ mysql
  Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
  Your MySQL connection id is 22
  Server version: 8.0.36-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 (Ubuntu)

  Copyright (c) 2000, 2024, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

  Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
  affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
  owners.

  Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

  mysql>
  ```
- Connecting use PHP from CLI

  ```
  $ cat test.php
  <?php
  $conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);

  if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  }
  echo "Connected successfully";

  $ php test.php
  Connected successfully
  ```

But when try the same exact PHP script, but executed through Apache, it fails.

```
[Sun Mar 03 04:55:07.434839 2024] [php:error] [pid 172] [client 172.17.0.1:43990] 
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: 
Permission denied in /app/index.php:12\n
Stack trace:\n
#0 /app/index.php(12): mysqli->__construct()\n
#1 {main}\n
  thrown in /app/index.php on line 12
```

After hours of search, it seems like this is either caused by SELinux or Docker. I don't think SELinux is installed? (at least `sestatus` returns `command not found`). I also tried running the container using `--privileged` and/or `--security-opt label:disable`, no luck. Someone suggested running `chcon -t httpd_sys_content_t` on the files, but it only returns `chcon: can't apply partial context to unlabeled`. I also tried installing SELinux (`policycoreutils selinux-utils selinux-basics`), but I can never get it to enable?

Hopefully someone knows the root cause of the issue, and possibly a solution.